# How to remove json object based on if condition

Tags: karate

I want to remove a json object from the payload based on the condition if exists.

I am try to get this done by using the following code line:

```
And if (reqq[0].attributes.length!=0) remove reqq[0].attributes[0].id
```

But I am getting this error:

```
>>>> js failed:
01: if (reqq[0].attributes.length!=0) remove reqq[0].attributes[0].id
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:41 Expected ; but found reqq
if (reqq[0].attributes.length!=0) remove reqq[0].attributes[0].id
```

Can someone help to get this done?

Comment: I got this resolved with the following lines of code :

* def reqObj = reqq[0]
 And eval if (reqq[0].attributes.length!=0) karate.remove('reqObj', '<value>')